# Fill missing values of a column by mapping the column values with a different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

The dataframe looks like this:

| Year | Month |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | 10 |
| 2021 | 11 |
| 2021 | 12 |
| 2022 | 1 |
| 2022 | 2 |
| 2022 | 3 |
| NaN | 1 |

I have to fill the null value in the year column by checking the year of the corresponding month column, i.e., if the month is 1,2 or 3, year should be 2022 or if the month is 10,11 or 12, year should be 2021.

For this example, i need to fill the NaN value of year with 2022. What is the most proficient way of using pandas to solve this?

Comment: what should happen for other values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m = df['Year'].isna()

df.loc[m, 'Year'] = np.select([df.loc[m, 'Month'].between(1, 3),
                               df.loc[m, 'Month'].between(10, 12)],
                              [2022, 2021])
# if you want integers
df = df.convert_dtypes()
```

Output:

```
   Year  Month
0  2021     10
1  2021     11
2  2021     12
3  2022      1
4  2022      2
5  2022      3
6  2022      1
```

Comment: I switched [2021, 2022] to get the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

use `map` & `fillna`

```
m = {1:2022, 2:2022, 3:2022, 10:2021, 11:2021, 12:2021}
out = df.assign(Year=df['Year'].fillna(df['Month'].map(m)).astype('int'))
```

out:

```
Year    Month
0   2021    10
1   2021    11
2   2021    12
3   2022    1
4   2022    2
5   2022    3
6   2022    1
```

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Year': [2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, None], 
         'Month': [10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Comment: Suggestion: `m = dict(enumerate([2022]*3 + [2021]*9, 1))`